# How to clear already registered urlSchemeHandler from WKWebViewConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have added custom urlSchemeHandler for my WKWebViewConfiguration. I am maintaining a common WKWebViewConfiguration instance across the app and is being used in multiple places. If I try to add a scheme and if it is already added the app is crashing, Is it possible to clear and reassign the handler?

```
 configuration.setURLSchemeHandler(self, forURLScheme: "customHandler")
```

I am able to fetch the handler if it is already added. I want to reassign a new handler.

```
configuration.urlSchemeHandler(forURLScheme: "customHandler")
```

Answer (score 0):

let reconfigure `configuration` variable and assign again to `WKWebView` see the following code.

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.setURLSchemeHandler(CustomeSchemeHandler(), forURLScheme: "custom-scheme")
wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero,configuration:configuration)
```